# Scrape 'deep' audio features using Spotipy python library

Tags: python, api, spotify, business-process-management, spotipy

For the past few days, I've been using the excellent [Spotipy](http://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) python library for the Spotify Web API. Having navigated my way to accessing the basic information, however (track/artist/album names, urls, uris, etc), I'm now trying to find some deeper track features (BPM, tempo, etc).

I know that Spotify makes this information publicly available because [some enterprising services](http://static.echonest.com/SortYourMusic/) have already integrated these into their offerings. My question is, is there any way to access this sort of information through the `spotipy.Spotify()` object or is it simply not attainable as of the latest spotipy release (v2.3.8)?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That link is not an enterprising service, it is part of the examples for the Echo nest parts of the Spotify Web API.

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/#echo-nest-example-apps
https://github.com/plamere/SortYourMusic

What might be confusing is that the attributes are not available on the track object, but you need to call a new method called audio_features.

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-several-audio-features/
http://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#spotipy.client.Spotify.audio_features

This worked for me:

```python
import spotipy
import spotipy.oauth2

credentials = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyClientCredentials()
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=credentials)
print spotify.audio_features(['4uLU6hMCjMI75M1A2tKUQC'])
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I saw in the v2.3.8 overview that 'audio_features' had been added but couldn't find it in the related documentation; clearly I didn't try hard enough. Thanks again.